# When I Run Build Webpack, My Website Display Error (Mess)

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, web-component

When the NPM Run Build Webpack was successful, but the total appearance of the Messy Website, more precisely the navigation menu (main-menu) and footer (menu-down) there might be an error in the custom element but I don't know the location of the error.

This is my example code:

```js
let MenuUtamaElement = document.querySelector("menu-utama");
let MenuBawahElement = document.querySelector("menu-bawah");
let ContentNewsElement = document.querySelector("menu-bawah");

$(document).ready(function () {

  let url = "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=id&category=technology&apiKey=ca5b6461d1d543d893339c704b9836ea";

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",

    beforeSend: () => {
      $(".progress").show();
    },

    complete: () => {
      $(".progress").hide();
    },

    success: function (newsdata) {
      let output = "";
      let latestNews = newsdata.articles;
      for (let i in latestNews) {
        output += `
          <div class="col l6 m4 s12">
          <div class="card medium hoverable">
            <div class="card-image">
              <img src="${latestNews[i].urlToImage}" class="responsive-img" alt="${latestNews[i].title}">
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <span class="card-title activator"><i class="material-icons right">more_vert</i></span>
              <h6 class="truncate"><a href="${latestNews[i].url}" target="_blank" title="${latestNews[i].title}">${latestNews[i].title}</a></h6>
              <p><b>Sumber</b>: ${latestNews[i].source.name} </p>
            </div>

            <div class="card-reveal">
              <span class="card-title"><i class="material-icons right">close</i></span>
              <p><b>Deskripsi</b>: ${latestNews[i].description}</p>
            </div>

            <div class="card-action light-blue darken-3">
              <a href="${latestNews[i].url}" target="_blank" class="btn yellow darken-3"><span class="material-icons">
              label_important
              </span>Selanjutnya</a>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
        `;
      }

      if (output !== "") {
        $("#newsResults").html(output);
      }

    },

    error: function () {
      let errorMsg = `<div class="errorMsg center">Mohon Maad ada yang error</div>`;
      $("#newsResults").html(errorMsg);
    }
  })

});
```

```css
/*!
 * Materialize v1.0.0 (http://materializecss.com)
 * Copyright 2014-2017 Materialize
 * MIT License (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dogfalo/materialize/master/LICENSE)
 */


 #loader {
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

}

.progress {
    display: none;
}

.errorMsg {
    font-size: 34px;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Berita Mantap</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <!-- Tampilan Web -->
 <menu-utama></menu-utama>
   <content-news></content-news>
 <menu-bawah></menu-bawah>

 <!-- Javascript Disini -->
 <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
 <script src="js/menu-utama.js"></script>
 <script src="js/content-news.js"></script>
 <script src="js/menu-bawah.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's an example of my source code:

https://github.com/hahamen-ihs/berita-satu

Please help, sis, thank you very much :)